# Найти количество произведений пар чисел, которое кратно 10

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык, олимпиада

Добрый день, задача по олимпиадному программированию из егэ этого года.

На вход подается целое положительное число N, не превышающее 10000, и последовательность из N целых положительных чисел, не превышающих 1000. Программа должна выводить число пар чисел, произведение чисел в которых кратно 10. При этом числа, произведение которых мы проверяем на кратность, не обязаны стоять рядом: пара может составляться и из чисел, взятых с разных концов последовательности. 
Пример входных данных:

```
4
2 5 7 4
```

Пример выходных данных:

```
2
```

Здесь подходят пары (2;5) и (5;4).

Решение перебором очевидно, но меня интересует решение эффективное по памяти и по времени. Под эффективностью по времени и по памяти в егэ подразумевают следующее:

> Программа считается эффективной по времени, если время работы программы пропорционально количеству пар чисел N, т. е. при увеличении N в k раз время работы программы должно увеличиваться не более чем в k раз.
>   Программа считается эффективной по памяти, если размер памяти, использованной в программе для хранения данных, не зависит от числа N и не превышает 1 килобайта.

Очень интересно разобраться с этой задачей, буду благодарен за любую помощь. Язык программирования не важен, я хочу понять сам алгоритм.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Заводим массив `a` на 10 элементов - по остаткам от деления на 10.
2. Для каждого считанного числа `x` увеличиваем `a[x%10]`.
3. Считаем сумму:

   - Умножаем `a[0]` на сумму всех остальных элементов
   - Умножаем `a[5]` на значения по чётным индексам кроме 0
   - т. к. произведение двух кратных 10 чисел тоже делится на 10, `a[0] * (a[0]-1)`

Бррр... А теперь упрощаем:

- `a0` - количество чисел, которые делятся на 10
- `b0` - количество чисел, которые не делятся на 10
- `a2` - количество чисел, которые делятся на 2, но не на 10
- `a5` - количество чисел, которые делятся на 5, но не на 10

Обращаю внимание, что в `b0` входят `a2` и `a5`.

Ответ: `a0*(a0-1+b0) + a2*a5`.

И ещё упрощаем: `a0-1+b0` - это `n-1`.

PS: В соответствии с требованиями, надо не держать массив в памяти, а обрабатывать по мере чтения.

Comment: Отличное решение, спасибо :) И как я не догадался до этого сам...